# mahout GenericUserBasedRecommender

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am new for `Apache Mahout`. I am very confused how `GenericUserBasedRecommender` method works. For example:

```
UserSimilarity similarity =new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity (dataModel);  

UserNeighborhood neighborhood =new NearestNUserNeighborhood (2, similarity, dataModel);  

Recommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender (dataModel, neighborhood, similarity);  

Recommender cachingRecommender = new CachingRecommender(recommender);  

List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = cachingRecommender.recommend(12,10);
```

Result is:

```
user4 ­­­ 10.45  

user12 7.93  

user3 ­­­2.49
```

But, if I use `List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = cachingRecommender.recommend(12,5);`

There is no `recommendations`.

What is determined by the recommendations listed? Is there any threshold value ?

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps because of the low nearest neighbor threshold you have (2).
The similar users whom you consider for computing similarities probably dont have any overlap with item 5.

I suggest you increase the threshold of NearestNUserNeighborhood from 2 to maybe 5 or 10.
Also LogLikelihood or Tanimoto may perform better.